# Using Rlock/recursive lock in asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, locking, python-asyncio

I have some parts of my code that i need to lock, while i still want to be async.
The thing is that regular Lock is not good enough for me, because i have a generic function that handles failures, which will also need that lock.

Meaning inside that generic function, since i cant really know who called that function, i might try and lock the same lock twice in a row and get a deadlock.

As far as i know, thats a situation that can be solved using an RLock, but such thing does not exist for asyncio.

Is it possible to check if the current running task is holding a specific lock? whats the best practice to keep a state that could help me know if im already locking a specific lock and have no reason to re-lock it?

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the lock current state, and factor out the protected
body in a function -

i.e. instead of:

```
def errorhandler():
    with mylock:
        # error handling body
        ...
```

do

```
async def _innerhandler():
   # error handling body
   ...

async def errorhandler():
   if mylock.locked():
      return await _innerhandler()
   else:
      # *** see bellow
      async with mylock:
          return await _innerhandler
```

*** While the `await` in the async with will give space for the
lock to be acquired in other task, it should not result in a deadlock:
either the code that acquired the lock is independent from your
error handling, or it will call it eventually, in which
case the first branch will be picked.

Of course you have to take care of other state settings so that
tasks handled are not mistaken.